# Maven repo set but eclipse is showing compile time errors

Tags: eclipse, maven

I am using eclipse kepler with maven 3.1.1. I am not using embedded maven but using it externally. All dependencies are downloaded and war file generated by package goal.

But the problem is that eclipse is showing compile errors in whole workspace. I have set M2_REPO variable and added it in classpath but still same result.

Anybody help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You always have to post a portion of your compile errors stack, otherwise how would others know to help you.

Comment: Resolved. I had to convert that project into Maven project.